# british and non eu spouse migration

Tags: immigration, france, eu

I am a British citizen and my husband is South African and we reside in South Africa.  We are looking to relocate to Europe, possibly France.  Ok let me reword. The figure you mention here is quite reachable for us but does one have to find work within 3 months? We are not "professionals" but have worked all our lives and have experience. Myself in the office admin environment my husband would like to work for himself as handyman kind of thing. He also makes and restores wooden furniture and is a bit of an artist.

Comment: The amount of money required to qualify for residence as an economically non-active couple is about €15000 for a year, see http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/can-we-move-to-france-although-we-dont-live-in-the-eu

Comment: Are you intending to get a job in France? If so, do you have skills which are sufficiently in demand that you have good odds of getting a job within 3 months?

Comment: If you can edit your question to include details asked by Peter, please flag to reopen at that point.

Comment: It would be best to reformulate the question to make it self-contained (now it reads as part of a discussion) but I might be able to answer it. It's *either* €15000 in the bank *or* having work (even low pay part-time work would do, there are no income conditions in that case). And your husband finding work would not help. You, the EU citizen, need to find work (or qualify as a “economically non-active” resident), otherwise your husband cannot work without going through the usual immigration procedures, which are *much* more onerous.