# American long-term resident of UK retire to France

Tags: visa, us-citizens, france, resident-permit, uk-citizenship

My husband and I are American citizens with permits to permanently reside in the UK.  We have lived here since 2001 (my husband) and 2004 (myself).  We wish to move to France for retirement.

What type of permits and documentation are required for us to relocate and reside permanently in France?

Comment: Not a visa, but you do need a carte de séjour. You could avoid the need for one by first naturalizing in the UK, if you are eligible. But France seems to give permits fairly readily to the economically independent, so it may be less hassle to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can We Move To France Although We Don't Live In The EU?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/can-we-move-to-france-although-we-dont-live-in-the-eu)

Comment: VTC: while the question is slightly different, the dupe and multiple answers cover all the bases (particularly for this year-old question); OP has not returned to the site since.

Comment: I reviewed the answers to the proposed duplicate and all of them are based on atleast one of the partners being an EU citizen or a UK citizen. Neither of which is the case for this OP (both are non-UK/non-EU). They would fall under French law for strictly non-EU immigrants.